# Concatenate Strings with Context

Tags: code-golf, string

## Strings with Context

For the purposes of this challenge, a *string with context* is a triple of strings, called the *left context*, the *data part*, and the *right context*. It represents a substring of a longer string. We use the vertical pipe `|` as a separator, so an example of a string with context is `cod|e-go|lf`, where the left context is `cod`, the data is `e-go`, and the right context is `lf`. This example represents the substring `e-go` of `code-golf`.

Now, to concatenate two strings with context, we proceed as follows, using `aa|bcc|dee` and `cc|de|eee` as examples. We align the strings as in the diagram

```
a a|b c c|d e e
      c c|d e|e e e
```

so that their data parts are adjacent. The data part of the concatenation is the concatenation of the data parts, in this case `bccde`. The left context is the part that extends the furthers to the left of the first data part, in this case `aa`. Similarly, the right context is `eee`, so the concatenation is the string with context `aa|bccde|eee`. For a second example, consider `a|bb|cd` and `aabb|cd|`, where the second word has a empty right context. The alignment diagram is

```
  a|b b|c d
a a b b|c d|
```

where the left context of the second word extends further than that of the first. The concatenation is `aa|bbcd|`.

But wait, there's a gotcha: if the letters of the alignment diagram don't match, the concatenation doesn't exist! As an example, the diagram of `aa|bb|cc` and `c|c|c` is

```
a a|b b|c c
      c|c|c
```

where the `b` and `c` on the fourth column disagree, so they cannot be concatenated.

## The Task

Your job is to write a program that takes in two strings with context whose parts are separated by `|` as above, and outputs their concatenation if it exists, and something else if not. The "something else" can be any value, including no output, as long as it's not a valid string with context, and it is the same in all cases. However, throwing an error is not acceptable. You can give either a STDIN-to-STDOUT program or a function, and anonymous functions are accepted as well. The smallest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

## Test Cases

```
aa|bcc|dee cc|de|eee -> aa|bccde|eee
a|bb|cd    aabb|cd|  -> aa|bbcd|
a|b|cccd   aab|cc|c  -> aa|bcc|cd
a|b|c      b||cd     -> a|b|cd
aa|bb|cc   c|c|c     -> None
aaa|b|c    abb|cd|d  -> None
|bb|cd     abb|c|ed  -> None
a|b|c      a||cd     -> None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Haskell, <s>184</s> <s>182</s> <s>201</s> <s>199</s> 155

```
s&t|(a,'|':b)<-f t,(x,'|':y)<-f$r s,x#b,a#y=r(y!r a)++b!r x|0<1=""
r=reverse
a!b=a++drop(length a-1)b
(#)a=and.zipWith(==)(r a).filter h
f=span h
h=(/='|')
```

example run:

```
"|a|"&"|b|" -- returns "|ab|"
"|a|x"&"|b|" -- returns ""
```

if there isn't a match an empty string will be returned. otherwise the result would be returned.

**partial explanation:**

`#` is a function which gets two strings, and returns whether or not they match.

`!` gets two strings and returns the first one concatenated with extra character from the second (if there are any).

the main function `&` uses `span (/='|')` to split the inputs into two parts, `a|b|c` to `a, b|c`, checks if the contexts match, and then uses `!` twice to assemble the output.

**Edit:** mage-late regolfing seems to be pretty effective.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid that throwing an error is not an acceptable output method, especially for a function. Adding `|1<2=""` to the definition of `&` should solve that. I'm sorry I didn't specify this more explicitly in the specs, I'll edit it in.

Comment: @Zgarb Actually, this would not fix it. Is returning a string with too many `'|'` signs when the strings don't match okay?

Comment: Sure, as long as it is the same string for all non-matching inputs.

Answer (score 3):

## Python (242 bytes)

```py
import itertools as i
s='|'
j=''.join
r=reversed
m=lambda a,b:j(j(*set(p+q))for p,q in i.izip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=''))
def c(A,B):
 u,v,w,x,y,z=(A+s+B).split(s)
 try:return j(r(m(r(u+v),r(x))))[:-len(v)]+s+v+y+s+m(w,y+z)[len(y):]
 except:0
```

### Explanation

The lambda function `m` returns the longer of two strings as long as they share a common prefix. It does this by concatenating the empty string `''` in place of any missing values, then turning the result (which may take the forms `aa`, `ab`, `a`, or `b` in cases of match/mismatch/unequal lengths) into a set of unique characters at each position. `join` expects a single argument, so unpacking a set with more than one element will cause it to raise a `TypeError`.

The main function then

- uses `m` to combine the *left context and data part* the first word with the *left context* of the second (from right to left over reversed strings)
- concatenates data parts,
- and again uses `m` to combine the *right context of the first word* with the *data part and right context* of the second

The two original words' data parts are trimmed from the right and left sides of the new contexts.

Since we know that misalignments cause `m` to raise a `TypeError`, in these cases we catch the exception and implicitly return `None`.

### Testing

```py
TESTCASES = [
    ('aa|bcc|dee', 'cc|de|eee', 'aa|bccde|eee'),
    ('a|bb|cd', 'aabb|cd|', 'aa|bbcd|'),
    ('a|b|cccd', 'aab|cc|c', 'aa|bcc|cd'),
    ('a|b|c', 'b||cd', 'a|b|cd'),
    ('aa|bb|cc', 'c|c|c', None),
    ('aaa|b|c', 'abb|cd|d', None),
    ('|bb|cd', 'abb|c|ed', None),
    ('a|b|c', 'a||cd', None),
]

for A, B, R in TESTCASES:
    print '{:<10} {:<9} -> {}'.format(A, B, c(A, B))
```

### Output

```
aa|bcc|dee cc|de|eee -> aa|bccde|eee
a|bb|cd    aabb|cd|  -> aa|bbcd|  
a|b|cccd   aab|cc|c  -> aa|bcc|cd 
a|b|c      b||cd     -> a|b|cd    
aa|bb|cc   c|c|c     -> None      
aaa|b|c    abb|cd|d  -> None      
|bb|cd     abb|c|ed  -> None      
a|b|c      a||cd     -> None
```